# Python multiprocessing is slower than regular. How can I improve?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Basically have a script that combs a dataset of nodes/points to remove those that overlap. The actual script is more complicated but I pared it down to basically a simple overlap check that does nothing with it for demonstration.

I tried a few variants with locks, queues, pools adding one job at a time versus adding in bulk. Some of the worst offenders were slower by a couple order of magnitude. Eventually I got it to the fastest I could.

The overlap checking algorithm which is send to the individual processes:

```
def check_overlap(args):
    tolerance = args['tolerance']
    this_coords = args['this_coords']
    that_coords = args['that_coords']

    overlaps = False
    distance_x = this_coords[0] - that_coords[0]
    if distance_x <= tolerance:
        distance_x = pow(distance_x, 2)
        distance_y = this_coords[1] - that_coords[1]
        if distance_y <= tolerance:
            distance = pow(distance_x + pow(distance_y, 2), 0.5)
            if distance <= tolerance:
               overlaps = True

    return overlaps
```

The processing function:

```
def process_coords(coords, num_processors=1, tolerance=1):
    import multiprocessing as mp
    import time

    if num_processors > 1:
        pool = mp.Pool(num_processors)
        start = time.time()
        print "Start script w/ multiprocessing"

    else:
        num_processors = 0
        start = time.time()
        print "Start script w/ standard processing"

    total_overlap_count = 0

    # outer loop through nodes
    start_index = 0
    last_index = len(coords) - 1
    while start_index <= last_index:

        # nature of the original problem means we can process all pairs of a single node at once, but not multiple, so batch jobs by outer loop
        batch_jobs = []

        # inner loop against all pairs for this node
        start_index += 1
        count_overlapping = 0
        for i in range(start_index, last_index+1, 1):

            if num_processors:
                # add job
                batch_jobs.append({
                    'tolerance': tolerance,
                    'this_coords': coords[start_index],
                    'that_coords': coords[i]
                })

            else:
                # synchronous processing
                this_coords = coords[start_index]
                that_coords = coords[i]
                distance_x = this_coords[0] - that_coords[0]
                if distance_x <= tolerance:
                    distance_x = pow(distance_x, 2)
                    distance_y = this_coords[1] - that_coords[1]
                    if distance_y <= tolerance:
                        distance = pow(distance_x + pow(distance_y, 2), 0.5)
                        if distance <= tolerance:
                            count_overlapping += 1

        if num_processors:
            res = pool.map_async(check_overlap, batch_jobs)
            results = res.get()
            for r in results:
                if r:
                    count_overlapping += 1

        # stuff normally happens here to process nodes connected to this node
        total_overlap_count += count_overlapping

    print total_overlap_count
    print "  time: {0}".format(time.time() - start)
```

And testing function:

```
from random import random

coords = []
num_coords = 1000
spread = 100.0
half_spread = 0.5*spread
for i in range(num_coords):
    coords.append([
        random()*spread-half_spread,
        random()*spread-half_spread
    ])

process_coords(coords, 1)
process_coords(coords, 4)
```

Still, the non-multiprocessing runs in less than 0.4s consistently and the multiprocessing I can get just under 3.0s as it stands above. I get that maybe the algorithm here is too simple to really reap benefits, but considering the above case has nearly half a million iterations and the real case has significantly more, it's weird to me that the multiprocessing is an order of magnitude slower.

What am I missing / what can I do to improve?

Comment: So have you tried actually running it on your actual data and determining if the multiprocessing will be worthwhile? E.g instead of using half a million, do 5 million and see what happens? Premature optimization can cost you lots of time

Comment: @IanQuah, I tried it once and it was way slower, but I was using one of the abandoned methods that turned out to be inefficient, hence isolating and experimenting. That said, at this point it's more a personal curiosity. If I can't get such a seemingly simple use case to benefit, when do I ever use python multiprocessing?

Comment: Your computation isn't heavy enough to earn back the IPC overhead. Don't start thinking about using multiprocessing if your sequential code doesn't take some seconds to complete. Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343188/no-performance-gain-after-using-multiprocessing-for-a-queue-oriented-function/52348640#52348640) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52246574/concurrency-parallelism-on-windows-with-python/52249698#52249698) might improve your understanding.

Comment: @Darkonaut yeah more I read about seems like Python has a lot of overhead for multiprocessing compared to my other familiarity with it (mostly in Java). That said, the numpy suggestion in those links is a good workaround for basic math operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building `O(N**2)` 3-element dicts not used in the serialized code, and transmitting them over interprocess pipes, is a pretty good way to guarantee multiprocessing can't help ;-)  Nothing comes for free - everything costs.

Below is a rewrite that executes much *the same* code regardless of whether it's run in serial or multiprocessing modes.  No new dicts, etc.  In general, the larger `len(coords)`, the more benefit it gets from multiprocessing.  On my box, at 20000 the multiprocessing run takes about a third of the wall-clock time.

Key to this is that all processes have their own copy of `coords`.  This is done below by transmitting it just once, when the pool is created.  That should work on all platforms.  On Linux-y systems, it could happen "by magic" instead via forked process inheritance.  Reducing the amount of data sent across processes from `O(N**2)` to `O(N)` is a huge improvement.

Getting more out of multiprocessing would require better load balancing.  As is, a call to `check_overlap(i)` compares `coords[i]` to each value in `coords[i+1:]`.  The larger `i`, the less work there is for it to do, and for the largest values of `i` just the cost of transmitting `i` between processes - and transmitting the result back - swamps the amount of time spent *in* `check_overlap(i)`.

```
def init(*args):
    global _coords, _tolerance
    _coords, _tolerance = args

def check_overlap(start_index):
    coords, tolerance = _coords, _tolerance
    tsq = tolerance ** 2
    overlaps = 0
    start0, start1 = coords[start_index]
    for i in range(start_index + 1, len(coords)):
        that0, that1 = coords[i]
        dx = abs(that0 - start0)
        if dx <= tolerance:
            dy = abs(that1 - start1)
            if dy <= tolerance:
                if dx**2 + dy**2 <= tsq:
                    overlaps += 1
    return overlaps

def process_coords(coords, num_processors=1, tolerance=1):
    global _coords, _tolerance
    import multiprocessing as mp
    _coords, _tolerance = coords, tolerance
    import time

    if num_processors > 1:
        pool = mp.Pool(num_processors, initializer=init, initargs=(coords, tolerance))
        start = time.time()
        print("Start script w/ multiprocessing")
    else:
        num_processors = 0
        start = time.time()
        print("Start script w/ standard processing")

    N = len(coords)
    if num_processors:
        total_overlap_count = sum(pool.imap_unordered(check_overlap, range(N))) 
    else:
        total_overlap_count = sum(check_overlap(i) for i in range(N))

    print(total_overlap_count)
    print("  time: {0}".format(time.time() - start))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from random import random

    coords = []
    num_coords = 20000
    spread = 100.0
    half_spread = 0.5*spread
    for i in range(num_coords):
        coords.append([
            random()*spread-half_spread,
            random()*spread-half_spread
        ])

    process_coords(coords, 1)
    process_coords(coords, 4)
```

Comment: Oh, very interesting. Was not aware of `initializer`/`initargs` -- I was looking for a way to simply share data w/o the overhead of each process having to recreate it. Looking into that, I wonder if a `manager` instance would also help. But thanks, that opens up a lot of new ideas!